# ErrorCounter Unexpected Token where - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using jpa for queries. My query is this :

```
public PartsItem getAvailablePartsItem(String search) {
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    PartsItem pi;
    pi = s.createQuery("from PartsItem where lower(serialNumber) like lower(:serialNumber) and where available = true", PartsItem.class).setParameter("serialNumber",'%' + search + '%').list().get(0);
    s.close();
    return pi;
}
```

I get an error with unexpected tokens at with `where` and `available`. I want these two conditions fulfilled but I keep getting these errors. Could it be an issue with the `and`?

Comment: "JPA" doesn't have a SessionFactory or a Session. So no, you're *not* using JPA. And JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}", yet another reason you're not using JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the final `where` keyword, so removing that should make it parse successfully.